# Text longlistselector not completely visible

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a little problem using the `longlistselector` (well more specifically the `multilonglistselector`) in windows phone 8.

I use binding to bind the name of an object to the items, the XAML code is as follow:

```
<Grid>
<TextBox  x:Name="searchBox" 
IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" KeyUp="CheckKey" 
Height="72" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" InputScope="Search" GotFocus="Select"/>
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector EnforceIsSelectionEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="AdjustAddSelectionButton" x:Name="resultList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="434" Margin="10,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  TextWrapping="Wrap">
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
<toolkit:GestureListener DoubleTap="OpenArticleDetail" />
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</TextBlock>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
</Grid>
```

The Binding takes place perfectly, **but the text is sometimes too long and doesn't fit the screen. How would I go about wrapping this text to another line?**, [I 'll give a screenshot here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23729184/ScreenShot023.bmp)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really state any specific problem or question you want answered. Please try to be a bit more clear in the future.

If you don't like that the TextBlock cuts off words that it can't fit, then you have several solutions.

1. TextBlocks have a TextWrapping property, so doing `TextWrapping="Wrap"` will enable the TextBlock to resize itself to display all the content.
2. TextBlocks have the TextTrimming property, so writing `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` will replace any cut off words with an ellipsis.
3. If you want to keep the one line but also show all the content, you can put the TextBlock inside a Horizontal ScrollViewer, which will let the user scroll the text left and right. Not great, but a decent solution

Code for 3.

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <TextBlock Text="Text"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as you can see, the TextWrapping="Wrap" is enabled, I have also tried the TextTrimming option, both don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I added a huge right padding to my main TextBlock to work around this issue.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-4,-50,0">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="30" Padding="0,0,125,0"/>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Fill="#78c5a6" Margin="0,18,0,18"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```